# NetBeans not parsing CMake defines

Tags: netbeans, cmake, config

I'm using NetBeans to work on an existing CMake project.

In *CMakeLists.txt* there is

```
set(DEFINES ${SRC}/defines.cmake)
```

So when in source you have

```
#ifdef MY_OPT
//do stuff
#endif
```

these are blanked out in NetBeans, because there is never a

```
#define MY_OPT
```

Instead there is a

```
-DMY_OPT
```

in *defines.cmake*.

How can I tell NetBeans to look into this file (and others)?

Comment: Into which file? Do you have a config.h file or similar? If not, how should NetBeans figure out what your scripts are doing?

Comment: Hi @usr1234567 , I edited the original question to provide the information you were asking. I was not precise enough.

Comment: I assume your defines.cmake will have an effect on some header (usually config.h) which is then used in your C or C++ code, right? NetBeans does not parse CMake files to virtually generate a config.h to tho the highlighting right. Whatever is inside defines.cmake, cannot directly influence your C(++) code, thus NetBeans has no chance to figure out what you request.

Comment: @usr1234567 Is it possible that this defines.cmake file actually sets the defines through the pre-processor instead? Kinda like an env setting throughout compilation. If so what options do I have to allow an IDE to understand what's happening?

Comment: `-DMY_OPT` could be arguments for CMake or for the C preprocessor (aka compiler). So, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
set(DEFINES ${SRC}/defines.cmake)
```

What is this line intended to do? If your `defines.cmake` contains some preprocessor settings, you better use [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/include.html):

```
include("${SRC}/defines.cmake")
```

---

> Is it possible that this defines.cmake file actually sets the defines through the pre-processor instead?

Yes, this is where [add_definitions()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_definitions.html) will help:

```
add_definitions(-DMY_OPT -DANOTHER_ONE)
```

---

To sum it up:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# ...
include("${SRC}/defines.cmake")
# ...
```

**defines.cmake**

```
# Add defines
add_definitions(-DMY_OPT)
```

**Somewhere in your source:**

```
#ifdef MY_OPT
    /* This is used now */
#else
    /* MY_OPT is not defined - shouldn't happen now */
#endif
```

Btw., you may also have a look at [`configure_file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/configure_file.html).

Comment: thanks it looks like the right way. I now have a host of cmake errors because every subfolder has a CMakeLists.txt file with "include (${DEFINES})" command.
I tried commenting those out, but then I have compilation errors and my assumption is that defines are not propagated correctly through the folder tree.

Suggestions?

Comment: By the way: the code compiles and works. It's the IDE that's unable to understand which defines are set and which are not. So I'm struggling to understand how to pass the knowledge of the pre-processor to the IDE.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a minimal example? What version of NB are you using?